# Convert week.year to year.month - date in R

Tags: r, date

I would like to convert a date week.year ("44.2016") to year.month (2016-11) in ISO 8601

I have a variable `date_week <- "44.2016"`

I tried this :

```
as.Date(date_week, format = "%U.%Y")

as.Date(date_week, format = "%W.%Y")
```

I have this result: `"2016-02-21"`

I also tried this :

```
as.Date(date_week, format = "%w.%Y")

as.Date(date_week, format = "%w.%Y")
```

result : `NA`

I would like to have this RESULT : `"2016-11"`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: would this help? `format(tail(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), by="1 day", length.out=44*7), 1L), "%Y-%m")`

Comment: `as.Date(paste("1", date_week, sep = "."), format = "%w.%W.%Y")`?

Comment: It looks like the 44th week of 2016 actually started the 31st october

Comment: No, it doesn't work @chinsoon12

Comment: Yeah it works @ANG !

Thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you need to specify a day since a week can imply two consecutive months. Try this:

```
as.Date(paste("1", date_week, sep = "."), format = "%w.%W.%Y") # 1st day (monday 31 oct 2016)
as.Date(paste("2", date_week, sep = "."), format = "%w.%W.%Y") # 2nd day (Tuesday 01 nov 2016)
# new format 
format(as.Date(paste("1", date_week, sep = "."), format = "%w.%W.%Y"), "%Y-%m")
# [1] "2016-10"
format(as.Date(paste("2", date_week, sep = "."), format = "%w.%W.%Y"), "%Y-%m")
# [1] "2016-11"
```